# jQM how to clear a listview search and its 'delete-icon'

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm able to clear the text in the search field, with `$("#my_div").find("input").val("");` But it leaves the grey delete-icons ("clear text"). How can I reset the listview so they also disappear?

```
<div id="my_div">
<ul id="search1" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search1..." ></ul>
<ul id="search2" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search2..." ></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see neither `<input>` nor grey icons in your HTML.

Comment: @Regent this a filterable listview, the search input is created dynamically.

Comment: @Omar yes, this is what my comment is about: people don't care to post final (after jQM wraps "all that can see") HTML here with related CSS. Somehow it turns out that I should create fiddle just to figure out how final HTML looks like, even though it's not me who is seeking for help.

Comment: @Regent you're absolutely correct. check jqm's [wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-mobile/info), I added "_How do I ask a good question on jQuery-Mobile?_" but looks like nobody reads it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have posted both version. Mine + the version after jQM adds it's custom styling

Comment: @BakedInhalf adding more details will make your question understandable by many users not only jQM ones. Its a good one anyway but missing some details ;)

Comment: @Omar Yes you are correct, I will do so next time! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.val("")` isn't enough, you need to `.focus()` and `.trigger("change")` as well. This way, you inform jQM that the value has been changed in order to hide *clear button*.

```
$("#my_div")
     .find("input")
     .val("")
     .focus()
     .trigger("change");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/qnknsg3v/)**